# Incorrect song length in Banshee

Tags: banshee

I've noticed that Banshee displays incorrect length for some songs. For example, I have a song that's only a few minutes long, but in the playlist it says that it's 30:43.

Everything plays just fine, so I guess it's just incorrect metadata somwhere.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'd suggest trying with another song and if the problem persist, sending a bug report to banshee developers.

Comment: It affects about 5 out of 4000 songs, so I really think there's something wrong with the information in the audio files. Can I edit this information somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ex Falso](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/exfalso/) to edit mp3 etc. tags, but I'm not sure if song duration is exported from those. But give it a try. Maybe there is a corruption in those files, possibly they are created via a buggy software.